# Change the text of "too localized" in the meta close reasons

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

From a certain perspective, every post on meta fits the definition of too localized since they're all about "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet", namely, meta.  With respect to meta, I suggest we drop the final clause.  This would prevent [bug reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/suspension-message-needs-to-include-the-year-when-showing-an-actual-date) from being closed as "too localized" simply because the bug is rare ("an extraordinarily narrow situation"). While you might choose to prioritize a bug (or reject the report as by design), ignoring it because it only affects a very small number of people would be wrong, IMO.

> This question would only be relevant
>   to a small geographic area or  a
>   specific moment in time.

Comment: It won't prevent it from being closed as `[status-bydesign]` though.

Comment: I've noticed a recent trend that when people come here for a problem with their account (i.e. customer/technical support), it get a random "too localized" vote to close. That's almost *certainly* not what "too localized" was intended to be applied to.

Comment: @Robert: What do you want? If there *are only 3 choices*...

Comment: Point being that we should *not* vote-to-close customer support questions... simply on the basis that it only involves that one person. *"I need help with my account"* is not "too localized." It's customer support. Unfortunately, I can't find a good example at the moment.

Answer (score 12):

I strongly agree with this. **And not just on Meta**. For me "too localized" is for questions like

> Why is there a green Honda Civic parked in front of my house?

It's being (mis)used to close just about any question that mentions a place or time. See my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized/87415#87415).

I propose just truncating the last few words from the close reason ("...that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet"). There are literally NO questions on Stack Exchange AT ALL that are "generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" so this clause ends up being a gigantic loophole and leads well-meaning hall-monitor-types to vote to close all kinds of questions that are genuinely useful. ([example](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/536/how-are-the-fukushima-questions-too-localized))

It almost never makes sense to close a question just because it is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer the following verbage:

*"This question would only be relevant to one whiny person."*

Comment: ...and, again, we close all questions on meta.  :-)