# Isn't everything on meta too localized?

Tags: discussion

Can we please remove the too localized reason from meta?

Related: [Change the text of "too localized" in the meta close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42408/change-the-text-of-too-localized-in-the-meta-close-reasons)

It seems that mostly everything on meta is related to one time or another and can technically beclosed as localed (along with this question as well)

For example: [This recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159113/155556) MSO question be closed as localized? It is referring to a specific dat "May 14th" but it is also referring to the Community User at large, and trying to understand how that works.

Comment: Generally when I vote to close things as too localized here on Meta, it's for things that really *never were* a problem in the first place. This applies to retag requests in which there was nothing to retag or so few things to retag that it didn't deserve a question, or for browser-specific bug reports that turn out to be total junk. The close reason is still valid and applicable to questions.

Comment: It's been a while since we've had a "my question got closed, so let's change the whole close feature" post. I don't know if we've ever had one as a reaction to a meta post, actually

Comment: @MichaelMrozek baaah I was thirsty.... and my head hurts....

Comment: Adding to what @animuson already said, I vote to close as "too localized" questions that are inane, and mostly serve to push other, more helpful questions out of the way.

Comment: @Yannis even when one is curious about the runnings of the Stack Exchange? (to be specific on my question)

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Meta's primary function are to help people understand the platform and culture of the main site, and discuss policy. The company's internal workings may be interesting, but so are a ton of other things, curiosity alone isn't exactly a great reason to post on Meta. A lot of SE employees are active in various chat rooms, why not ask them such questions in chat?

Comment: @Yannis if someone else has the same Q, should they also bother the devs again?

Comment: First "too localized" close vote is in already... (not me).

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA My personal opinion is that they shouldn't, they should realize that their question is inane, and find something a bit more productive to do with their time. But if they can't help themselves and _must_ ask, then chat would be preferable.

Comment: @Neal, the question you link to in your edit arguably looks more interesting than a request for information about some of the staff's job positions, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi well the same goes for the questions about the inner working of the SE, it is localized to a small group of people, but people still **want** to know about it!

Comment: Ah, but to me there is a big difference between questions about the SE network and questions about the *people* that run the network.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: What color toothpaste does Nick Craver use? ;-)

Comment: @Manishearth, for a while I considered including such a contrived example in my last comment. My personal pick was *Why has Yannis Rizos's avatar been pitch black for a few weeks now?* ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Contrived? _How dare you_! I genuinely want to know what color toothpaste is best for devs!

Comment: @Manishearth, I would not *dare* asking that, even in chat. You never know what the answers would be. They may even include pictures.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Not any more ;)

Comment: @Yannis, is that recent? I still see you as black on meta, and `Ctrl+Shift+R` achieves nothing. Probably, let me guess... server-side caching, as usual :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, it's a bit recent, my new gravatar is holiday themed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Try: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76dd4603df4c1c437fe9a708b31feb17?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&

Comment: I like it. The expression on his face probably means he's looking at the review queues or some even deeper horror.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Don't forget: I moderate Programmers ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't close it, but if I could, it would probably be as NC. I agree completely with [Yannis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159112/isnt-everything-on-meta-too-localized#comment460712_159112):

> I vote to close as "too localized" questions that are inane, and mostly serve to push other, more helpful questions out of the way.

See, meta allows fun. Fun isn't off topic. BUT, fun takes away attention from other posts, which isn't too good. We don't have a standard close reason for it, but I personally feel that fun posts should be kept for a while (let everyone have their "fun"), and then closed. This sounds suspiciously similar to "too localized" posts -- they are applicable for a short time, and don't really need to stick around long-term, which is why they're closed.

Remind yourself the of the primary purpose of meta, and move on. The post got answered to the fullest extent. You had your fun, no need to whine about it.

Comment: Did RobertHarvey really just historical lock my question!?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Looks like it... So?

Comment: That is not what that lock is for.

Comment: Heh, nice, I get to upvote myself!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Fully agree with you on this one, the question should be deleted, not locked.

Comment: @Yannis well no it should not be deleted.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA:  The question is actually deletable (IMO). He's locked it because of this meta post referring to it.

Comment: @Manishearth lol that never stops anyone from deleting anything. Then only the 10K users can see it.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Well, generally the 10k only links you see on meta are from posts which were deleted ages before the post referring to them was born.