# Why are all comments by Community User on 14 May?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-user, testing

On the [comments tab of the activity page on the network profile of the Community User](https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/-1?page=1&filter=comments), **all** comments are dated 14 May. They're all on Meta and of the nature of *We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)*. Why? Was there some experimenting going on?

Comment: That's probably the day the link checking script ran... They do normally experiment with new features on Meta (they were building a broken links review queue I believe) - probably the comments didn't get cleaned up.

Comment: See: [Does Stack Exchange crawl websites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130399)

Answer (score 2):

We are all [lab unicorns](http://noggly.deviantart.com/art/Unicorn-s-Laboratory-280747195). They do [eX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158762/whats-up-with-the-new-css)-[pe](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/)[RI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta)-[mENTs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) on all of us, all of the time...